# Split Everything before a particular pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String

```
Jon, Kim, Hem, David, Gary, Bryan, Otis, Neil, Blake, Greg, @Team=Cowboys, Chargers, Panthersm, Royals, Kings, Warriors
```

I want to split this string in java from all commas before `@Team` appears. The result should look like:

```
Jon
Kim
Hem
David
Gary
Bryan
Otis
Neil
Blake
Greg
@Team=Cowboys, Chargers, Panthersm, Royals, Kings, Warriors
```

My java code uses regex `(?<=)(?=@Team)` :

```
String data = "Jon, Kim, Hem, David, Gary, Bryan, Otis, Neil, Blake, Greg, @Team=Cowboys, Chargers, Panthersm, Royals, Kings, Warriors";
String arr[] = data.split("(?<=)(?=@Team)");
String temp[] = arr[0].split(",\\s");
String result[] = new String[temp.length + 1];

int i=0;
for(i=0; i<temp.length; i++)
    result[i] = temp[i];

result[i] = arr[1];

for(String s : result)
    System.out.println(s);
```

It does the job but there's a lot of boilerplate. Is there any regex so that I can do all this stuff in one shot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex `,\s(?=.*@Team)`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/SJwmsT/1)

This is basically looking for pairs of `,\s` followed by anything thats further followed by string `@Team`.

**Code**

```
String data = "Jon, Kim, Hem, David, Gary, Bryan, Otis, Neil, Blake, Greg, @Team=Cowboys, Chargers, Panthersm, Royals, Kings, Warriors";
String arr[] = data.split(",\\s(?=.*@Team)");
for(String s : arr) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

**Output**

```
Jon
Kim
Hem
David
Gary
Bryan
Otis
Neil
Blake
Greg
@Team=Cowboys, Chargers, Panthersm, Royals, Kings, Warriors
```

Comment: If there is no `@Team` in the input, split won't occur at all.

Answer (score 3):

This will work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "Jon, Kim, Hem, David, Gary, Bryan, Otis, Neil, Blake, Greg, @Team=Cowboys, Chargers, Panthersm, Royals, Kings, Warriors";
    // SPlit based on comma and space as long as there is a "@Test" later in the string
    String[] arr = s.split(",\\s+(?=.*@Team)");  
    for (String str : arr) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

O/P :

```
Jon
Kim
Hem
David
Gary
Bryan
Otis
Neil
Blake
Greg
@Team=Cowboys, Chargers, Panthersm, Royals, Kings, Warriors
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to achieve it :

```
List <String> splitString = new ArrayList<>(); //container for result
String data = "Jon, Kim, Hem, David, Gary, Bryan, Otis, Neil, Blake, Greg, @Team=Cowboys, Chargers, Panthersm, Royals, Kings, Warriors";

while ((data.indexOf("@") != 1) ){//stop when @ is reached 

    int index = data.indexOf(",");//location of first ,
    splitString.add( data.substring(0,index) ); //add substring to list
    data = data.substring(index+1);//remove substring from data
    index = data.indexOf(",");
}

splitString.add(data); //add what's left of data to result 

for(String s : splitString) {//output
    System.out.println(s);
}
```